# Swapping out a class for another in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty changing the class of a button element using jQuery. Currently, it adds an extra class to the button element.

This is my code so far. How can I resolve it?

```
$(function () {
    $("#admin").click(function () {
            $('#normal').show();
            $('#admin').hide();
            $('.delete_admin').toggleClass("delete_normal");
            return false;
    });
    $("#normal").click(function () {
        $('#normal').hide();
        $('#admin').show();
        $('.delete_normal').toggleClass("delete_admin");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements starts out with one class, you toggle both classes, removing the existing one, and adding a new one, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#admin").click(function () {
        $('#normal').show();
        $('#admin').hide();
        $('.delete_admin').toggleClass("delete_normal delete_admin");
        return false;
    });
    $("#normal").click(function () {
        $('#normal').hide();
        $('#admin').show();
        $('.delete_normal').toggleClass("delete_normal delete_admin");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest jQuery library, you can use below script..

```
   $(function () {
        $("#admin").on("click",function() {
            $('#normal').show();
            $('#admin').hide();
            $('.delete_admin').toggleClass("delete_normal delete_admin");
            return false;
        });

        $("#normal").on("click",function(){
            $('#normal').hide();
            $('#admin').show();
            $('.delete_normal').toggleClass("delete_normal delete_admin");
        });
    });
```